# Invalid use of non static data member C++

Tags: c++

Here is my code

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "header.h"
#include "source.cpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    int testarray[]={1,3,5,7};
    mymatrix* first=new mymatrix(testarray,2,2);
    return 0;
}
```

and header.h

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class mymatrix{
public:
    int i;
    int j;
    int marray[];

    mymatrix(int m[],int rows,int cols ) : marray(m),i(rows),j(cols)
    {
        cout<<"this is for testings ";
    }
    mymatrix()
    {};
    ~mymatrix(){
    // delete[] marray;
    };


};
```

I get this error :Invalid use of non static data member mymatrix::i

what I wanna do is make a object of my
matrix class and pass an array

Comment: What does `marray[][]` mean?

Comment: In which line do you get this error?

Comment: int i ,int j  << thats the line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert it from

```
int marray[];
```

to

```
int *marray;
```

In addition, either use C paradigm or use C++ one but not the mixture.

Instead of

```
mymatrix* first=new mymatrix(testarray,2,2);
```

use

```
mymatrix first(testarray,2,2);
```

Let the compiler allocate and release the memory instead of you.

If you have no restriction about the C++ libraries that you use, consider `std::vector` library to manage your dynamic arrays.

Instad of managing memory out of the object, manage it inside the object specially inside constructor and destructor.

Comment: Thanks ,but the problem occured for int i and int j .This advice is helpfull though

Comment: wow i removed  ": marray(m),i(rows),j(cols)" part and appiled this then i works .thanks a lot